# How to add application to the record/broadcast section of the control center in iOS11?

Tags: swift, screen-recording, replaykit

Does anyone know, how it is possible to add an application to the control center in iOS 11 like TeamViewer does?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: In Xcode: File-> New Target-> BroadcastUploadExtension

Comment: It worked, Thank you @KrisDude :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be possible by adding the Broadcast Upload Extension to your application. 
You can add the extension as below
File -> New -> Target -> Broadcast Upload Extension

Make sure that bundle ids for both targets (original app target and extension target) should start with the same string like below
App bundle id:- com.test.com.testapp
Extension bundle id:- com.asurion.com.testapp.BExtensionUpload